# Как установить LAMP Server на Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, установка, lamp

Пробовал все инструкции из интернета и мне вечно выдаёт страницу 404 Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80.
Пожалуйста помогите разобраться с этим.
Может есть другие аналоги вамп сервера?

Comment: [Установка LAMP](https://losst.ru/ustanovka-lamp-ubuntu-18-04) А так из твоего вопроса ничего не понятно, что делал, как делал. Напиши подробно, а то твой вопрос не есть гуд.

Comment: судя по приведённому тексту, как минимум программа apache у вас благополучно установлена и отлично работает. попробуйте разобраться, почему она выдаёт вам не ту информацию, которой вы, судя по всему, ожидаете. начните с логов этой программы.